# Does matlab's k-mean recompute the cluster membership of seeds?

Tags: matlab, statistics, cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am unable to find the details of `matlab's k-mean` about seeds. That if matlab's k-mean recomputes the cluster assignment of `Xs seeds`, which is subset of `data set X` matrix.

Or these seeds are only used for initial centered location and are not considered in k-means cluster assignment phase?

I want to `semi-supervised clustering by seeds` by Sugato Basu et.al
It might be a naive question but your answer would make this confusion clearer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, seeds are just used for the initial position.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the documentation: `doc kmeans`? There they use the term *initial cluster centroid positions* to refer to seeds.

In particular, look at the parameter named *start* which is used to specify the seeds, and the *replicates* parameter. Also see the *Algorithms* section, where they discuss the two phases of the process (batch update and online update). Finally, and perhaps best of all, you can look at the code directly with `edit kmeans`, and step through it with the debugger.

It's not clear to me exactly what your question is but, from the above, I would answer that the seeds are calculated once according to the 'start' parameter, followed by the batch update and online update. This is repeated according to the 'replicates' parameter.

I don't know what "semi-supervised clustering by seeds" is, but I'm pretty sure it's not supported out of the box.

Comment: Thank you, debugging kmeans code helped me alot to understand it as compared to using doc.